# I have created window service using visual studio 2012. When i installed that service, i got error

Tags: service

I have created window service using visual studio 2012. When i installed that service, i got  error.

Service cannot be started. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'SIPEPS, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'SIPEPS, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.Sample.Common.UCMASampleHelper.CreateEstablishedUserEndpoint(String endpointFriendlyName)
   at ACDService.ACD.OnStart(String[] args) in c:\Work\Ram\Lync\ACD\ACDService\ACD.cs:line 32
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

How to fix this issue?

I am using .NET Framework 4.5 and targeting x64.

Comment: Is that assembly in the GAC on the machine you're installing to?  How did you install it?

Comment: HOW did you install it?

Comment: i run this command gacutil -i SIPEPS.dll in vs commend prompt. I got response like 'Assembly successfully added to the cache'

Comment: What about dependencies?  I'm not familiar with SIPEPS.  Does it have its own installer, perhaps?

Comment: But i was unable to find it in C://windows/assembly folder

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration dll

Comment: Look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/a904249b-e8c1-4036-9895-1374ae59bcfc/sipeps-error-when-deploying-ucma-20-application-to-windows-server-2008r2?forum=ucmanagedsdk

Comment: i installed 64bit UCMA. But i have same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas :)

Comment: hi buddy, have you solved it? i meet the same problem. i am learning UCMA4 and wanted to give it a go. sadly, i see the problem at the scratch. i added two dlls: SIPEPS.dll and Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.SipEpsNet.dll. however, it doesnot work. if you have solved it, please notify me. many thanks!